# Ruby on Rails - force checkboxes to line up horizontally

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to get my checkboxes to line up horizontally instead of vertically and I'm having no luck here. The checkboxes and labels are stacking up next to each other as opposed to creating a new line each time.

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :phases, class: "col-sm-3 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes :phases, phases, :first, :first %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My form class is form-horizontal and everything else looks fine.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Got it by just adding col-sm-3 control-label as a class value to my collection_check_boxes. No longer need help unless there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `checkbox-inline` class to the ***label*** and you are good to go.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :phases, class: "checkbox-inline" %>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes :phases, phases, :first, :first %>
    </div>
</div>
```

From the [***Bootstrap Wiki***](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#inline-checkboxes-and-radios)

> Use the .checkbox-inline or .radio-inline classes on a series of
>   checkboxes or radios for controls that appear on the same line.

Comment: I tried this but this didn't work. Still showed them side by side for some reason.